# Can I order an IEnumerable in C#, using "OrderBy()" and some boolean?

Tags: c#, list, sorting, reverse, enumerable

As mentioned in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925258/c-sharp-list-orderby-descending), there are two ways to alter the direction of the ordering of a C# `List` (or any `Enumerable`):

- use the `OrderByDescending()` method.
- add `.Reverse()` at the end.

In my code, I have a lot of lines like these ones:

```
if (bDirection)
  list.OrderBy(...);
else
  list.OrderByDescending(...);
```

I would like to replace this by the following oneliner:

```
list.OrderBy(..., bDirection);
```

, where the `boolean bDirection` decides in which direction the ordering should be done.

Does this exist?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Write an extension methods that looks like it and contains the code you show you currently do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781990/how-do-i-specify-linqs-orderby-direction-as-a-boolean

Comment: A dumb code snipped that I use `var ordered = isAscending ? custom.OrderBy(c => c.Something) : custom.OrderByDescending(c => c.Something);` Just one line of code containing few characters more than other solutions.

Comment: `Reverse` is not a replacement for `OrderByDescending` since the latter expects either a key or a comparer, otherwise it doesn't know how to sort while `Reverse` always "reverses" the order of the sequence.